# use the output of a method in the middle of a writeline statement

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I am trying to get the output from a method i wrote in a different class to return a value into the middle of a writeline statement. The error "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'method group" is stopping anything from running, but I cant seem to find away to get the error resolved. This may be a real simple thing I am missing, but im still really new to programming so Im probably missing something obvious.

```
    public void EatFruits()
    {
        double dblpercent;
        this.MakeFruits();
        Console.WriteLine("You have an Apple and a Banana in your fruit garden.");
        Console.WriteLine("What Percent of the Apple would you like to eat?");
        dblpercent = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("What Percent of the Banana would you like to eat?");
        dblpercent = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("You have " + (apple.Eat) + "% of your apple and " + (banana.Eat) + "% of your banana left.");
    }
```

And the code for the Eat method in the other class is:

```
    public double Eat(double dblpercent)
    {
        return (PercentFruitLeft-dblpercent);
    }
```

PercentFruitLeft was set up early with a value of 100, and then decreased by whatever the user types in for how much they want to eat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method group is an expression used in the C# standard to describe a group of one or more overloaded methods identified by their common name. In this case, the compiler is referring to `apple.Eat` and `banana.Eat` method groups.

You need to call your method with a parameter in parentheses following the name of the method. In addition, you need separate `dblpercent` variables for the apples and for the bananas:

```
Console.WriteLine("What Percent of the Apple would you like to eat?");
double dblpercentApple = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("What Percent of the Banana would you like to eat?");
double dblpercentBanana = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("You have " + (apple.Eat(dblpercentApple)) + "% of your apple and " + (banana.Eat(dblpercentBanana)) + "% of your banana left.");
```

Rather than composing your strings manually with concatenations, you could use formatting, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("You have {0}"% of your apple and {1}% of your banana left.", apple.Eat(dblpercentApple), banana.Eat(dblpercentBanana));
```

This gives your code additional clarity by keeping the template of the string that you write together in a single string.